# Tell user if number entered is already stored inside the array

Tags: java

I have this code that asks the users to enter an array size (must not exceed 50) and the array size is successfully set to the array.

My problem is in the second piece of code.
Basically, I want it to store the numbers entered by the user (which works) BUT, if the number was already given to the array, the user is told that that number has already been added and the number is not stored. Example: User enter 1, 4, 6, 1. When 1 is given again the program should tell the user that the number 1 has already been stored in the array.

What can I do to make the program (with arraylists I could use .contains , but arrays dont have this it seems)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);

    int[] listA;

    while (true) {

        System.out.println("Enter array size for listA: ");
        int listAsize = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

        if (listAsize > 50) {

            System.out.println("Array size must not exceed 50!");

        } else { 

            listA = new int [listAsize];
            //System.out.println(listA.length);
            break;
        }

    }


    int counter = 0;

    while (counter < listA.length) {

        System.out.print("Enter number to add to listA: ");
        int inputListA = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

        **if (listA.equals(listA[counter])) {**

            System.out.println(inputListA + " was already added to the array, enter a different number");

        } else {


            listA[counter] = inputListA;
            counter++;

        }
    }
```

Comment: keep a ArrayList instead of array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This condition is incorrect:

```
listA.equals(listA[counter])
```

you need to set up a loop that goes from zero to `counter-1`, inclusive, and checks each element against the `inputListA` value. If a value is there, the loop should set a `boolean` flag, like this:

```
boolean dup = false;
for (int i = 0 ; i != counter ; i++) {
    if (listA[i] == inputListA) {
        dup = true;
        break;
    }
}
// If we went through listA up to count and dup remained false,
// listA must be a new number; otherwise, it's a duplicate.
if (dup) {
    System.out.println(inputListA + " was already added to the array, enter a different number");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked!
Exactly what I wanted, also thank you everyone else for your help as well
I have learned a lot from just reading all the codes everyone has given

Answer (score 2):

Problem in your code:

```
if (listA.equals(listA[counter]))
```

This is **not** going to be `true` for `int listA[]`

Use a `HashSet<Integer>` instead

- no need to specify initial size
- `add()` will return `false` if element is already present

Answer (score 2):

if you need it using array

```
int counter = 0;
while (counter < listA.length) {
    System.out.print("Enter number to add to listA: ");
    int inputListA = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    if (found(listA,inputListA,counter)) {
        System.out.println(inputListA + " was already added to the array, enter a different number");
    } else {
        listA[counter] = inputListA;
        counter++;
    }
}

public boolean found (int[]list,int num,int counter){
   for(int i = 0;i<counter;i++){
      if(list[i]==num)
        return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Or you can use hashset for a better performance

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and best solution is to use a HashSet (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

By restricting the user to only unique elements, you are saying 'I don't really want an array, I really want a set'

Answer (score 1):

If you must use arrays, but is not restricted from introducing array lists, you could probably use `Arrays.asList` to convert it to an array list.

```
Arrays.asList(yourArr).contains(someVal)
```

Or you could write your own `contains` method that simply loops over each element to see if it's in the array or not.

```
boolean hasElmt = false;
for (int val : yourArr) {
   if (val == someVal) {
      hasElmt = true;
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

since it is an array of primitive, there are no methods you can use. You have to iterate over the array using a `for` loop, and check the value for each index.

```
for(int i = 0; i < listA.lenght; i++) {
    if(inputListA == listA[i]) {
        // it's already on the array
    }
}
```